# CSS - currentwidth + px

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Is there any way to get the current width of the targeted object within CSS only?

I am messing around with animations and it would be really helpful with a feature like this.

Example:

```
/*What has to be done atm*/

@keyframes identifier {

  0%{width: 50px}
  25%{width: 100px}
  50%{width: 150px}
  75%{width: 200px}
  100%{width: 250px}

}

/*What I would like*/

@keyframes identifier {

  0%{width: currentwidth +50px}
  25%{width: currentwidth +50px}
  50%{width: currentwidth +50px}
  75%{width: currentwidth +50px}
  100%{width: currentwidth +50px}

}
```

With the last code it could actually just be a single step repeated as many times as i want to, is this possible?

Comment: you could create those animations in javascript or use precentages

Comment: Maybe `calc(100% + 50px)`?

Comment: you tagged this with `javascipt` but are looking for a css solution. Are you open to a javascript solution? What about a css pre-processor?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the calc(100% + 50px) will just set it to instantly fill 100% of the parent divs width and then + 50px. But thanks 

Comment: @MichaelCoker CSS pre-processor could be an option, i just wanted to know if it was possible with pure CSS. I see that i might have to go with SASS.

Comment: @LasseL cool, submitted an answer. You might update your post with the `scss` tag if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt at vars and loops in SCSS, so there may be a better way to do it. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/Zyydvw

HTML:

```
<div>foo</div>
```

SCSS:

```
$width: 0;
$percent: 0;
$increment: 50;

div {
  animation: identifier 5s forwards;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes identifier {

  @while $percent < 101 {
    #{$percent}% {
      width: calc(#{$width}px + #{$increment}px);
    }
    $width: $width + $increment;
    $percent: $percent + 25;
  }

}
```

Which compiles to

```css
div {
  animation: identifier 5s forwards;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes identifier {
  0% {
    width: calc(0px + 50px);
  }
  25% {
    width: calc(50px + 50px);
  }
  50% {
    width: calc(100px + 50px);
  }
  75% {
    width: calc(150px + 50px);
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(200px + 50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```